# Algebra of finite width matrices

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, coarse-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\FWM{FWM}\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$For any ring $R$ there's an *algebra of finite width matrices* with entries in $R$. By finite width matrices I mean the ones that have only finitely many nonzero *rows*. Let's call this algebra $\FWM(R)$. One may add the unit matrix to it to make it unital. $\FWM(R)$ is naturally a subalgebra of $\End \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$. $\End \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$ is also known as *column-finite matrices*, because it can be realised as the algebra of matrices that have finitely many nonzero entries in each column.

While $\End \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$ is pretty well-known and studied, $\FWM(R)$ appears to be quite mysterious; I haven't found any texts concerning its structure and/or categories of modules of any flavour. So, I'd like to know whether it was already studied (...it definitely was, but I didn't manage to find a way to figure out how people named this algebra) and what is already known about it.

Here are several questions that interest me particularly:

0. Does $\FWM(R)$ have any estabilished name?
1. What are the properties of left and right natural actions of  $\FWM(R)$ on $\bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$ and $\End \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$. Are they flat on either side?
2. What are the ways to define $\FWM(R)$ in a "coordinate-free" way, similar to its bigger cousin $\End \bigoplus_{\Bbb N} R$? Or, slightly differently put, does it have any universal properties?
3. Are there any nontrivial left or right simple modules over $\FWM(R)$?

I became interested in this algebra because I have a hunch that it should naturally act on the right on the space of coarse functions on *any* countable homogeneous coarse space. Typical example of such space is any countable group with its natural coarse structure. I had no success in proving that, and most approaches withered at the point where universal categorical reasoning met with ad hoc infinite matrix constructions. In particular, I suppose that there should be a bimodule structure on the space of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $R$ taking finitely many values (i. e. functions pulled back via a map from $\Bbb N$ to a finite set) but I currently have no understanding of the nature of this bimodule structure. In a sense, $\FWM(R)$ action should serve as an *underlying structure* of a coarse structure; this *underlying structure* being a choice of embedding of countable discrete set (countable group) into its Stone-Cech compactification, and "meaningful" part being the orbit decomposition under left regular action of group on itself.

Comment: Isnt this the ideal of endomorphisms with image contained in a finitely generated submodule of the infinite direct sum.  When R is a division ring these would be the finite rank endomorphisms. I guess if R is Noetherian on the correct side then this would be the endomorphisms with finitely generated image.  People certainly look at such things.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Well, yes, for matrix realization it's exactly finite rank endomorphisms; or, as one may say, algebra of compact operators for natural colimit topology. But I haven't found anything relevant! And it feels strange, because quotient by this ideal is very well studied Calkin algebra. Maybe I should have elaborated on meaning of "coordinate-free"; it would be very nice to get it as full endomorphism algebra of some natural *thing* (other than itself as a free rank one module). // Also I'm perfectly happy with R being a field.

Comment: If R is commutative and Noetherian then finite rank is a coordinate free description where finite rank means finitely generated image.

Comment: If R is a or division ring  then the natural action is simple and is the unique simple module up.to isomorphism

Comment: Also this ring is simple when R is a division ring.

Comment: If you look up the structure of primitive rings with a minimal left ideal you will find they are precisely the suhrings of column finite matrices over a division ring containing all the finite rank matrices.  This is a consequence of Jacobson's density theorem and can be found in Cohn's algebra book.

Comment: These days ring theorists don't tend to look at nonunital rings so one should probably look at older books